# R: "Animate" Points on a Scatter Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, animation, data-visualization

I am working with R. Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
 my_data <- data.frame(
"col" = c("red","red","red","red","red","blue","blue","blue","blue","blue","green", "green", "green", "green","green"),
"x_cor" = c(1,2,5,6,7,4,9,1,0,1,4,4,7,8,2),
"y_cor" = c(2,3,4,5,9,5,8,1,3,9,11,5,7,9,1),
"frame_number" = c(1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5)
)

my_data$col = as.factor(my_data$col)
head(my_data)

       col x_cor y_cor frame_number
1  red     1     2            1
2  red     2     3            2
3  red     5     4            3
4  red     6     5            4
5  red     7     9            5
6 blue     4     5            1
```

In R, is it possible to create a (two-dimensional) graph that will "animate" each colored point to a new position based on the "frame number"?

For example:
[image]

I started following the instructions from this website here: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/gganimate-how-to-create-plots-with-beautiful-animation-in-r/

First, I made a static graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

p <- ggplot(
    my_data, 
    aes(x = x_cor, y=y_cor,  colour = col)
```

Then, I tried to animate it:

```
p + transition_time(frame_number) +
  labs(title = "frame_number: {frame_number}")
```

Unfortunately, this produced an empty plot and the following warnings:

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

1: Cannot get dimensions of plot table. Plot region might not be fixed
2: values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 15
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: In `p`'s definition, isn't a `geom` layer missing?

Comment: Try `ggplot(
  my_data, 
  aes(x = x_cor, y=y_cor,  colour = col)) +
    geom_point() + 
  transition_time(frame_number) +
    labs(title = "frame_number: {frame_time}")`

Comment: @ Jon Spring: Thank you! This fixed the problem! Would you like to copy/paste this code into an answer so that future readers will know how to solve this problem? Or would you like me to do it? Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Can someone please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68564089/r-customizing-animation-text thanks!