# R: Customizing Animation Text

Tags: r, animation, dplyr, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
 my_data <- data.frame(
"col" = c("red","red","red","red","red","blue","blue","blue","blue","blue","green", "green", "green", "green","green"),
"x_cor" = c(1,2,5,6,7,4,9,1,0,1,4,4,7,8,2),
"y_cor" = c(2,3,4,5,9,5,8,1,3,9,11,5,7,9,1),
"kpi" = c(51,33,14,10,10, 62, 71, 52, 1, 7, 18, 22, 20,3,1 ),
"frame_number" = c(1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5)
)

my_data$col = as.factor(my_data$col)

head(my_data)
   col x_cor y_cor kpi frame_number
1  red     1     2  51            1
2  red     2     3  33            2
3  red     5     4  14            3
4  red     6     5  10            4
5  red     7     9  10            5
6 blue     4     5  62            1
```

In a previous question ([R: "Animate" Points on a Scatter Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68555168/r-animate-points-on-a-scatter-plot)) , I learned how to animate this data using the "gganimate" library:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

ggplot(   my_data,    aes(x = x_cor, y=y_cor,  colour = col)) +     geom_point() +    transition_time(frame_number) +     labs(title = "frame_number: {frame_time}")
```

[image]

**Question** Is it possible to also add some additional text to this graph, so that the value of the KPI column for each colored at each time frame is displayed, something like this?

[image]

Note: At each frame, "average_kpi" :
e.g.,

```
 "average_kpi_frame1" = (red_kpi_frame1 + green_kpi_frame1 + blue_kpi_frame1) / 3
 "average_kpi_frame2" = (red_kpi_frame2 + green_kpi_frame2 + blue_kpi_frame2) / 3
 "average_kpi_frame3" = (red_kpi_frame3 + green_kpi_frame3 + blue_kpi_frame3) / 3

etc
```

The "average_kpi" can be calculated as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

my_data$frame_number = as.factor(my_data$frame_number)

average_kpi = my_data %>%
    group_by(frame_number) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(Mean = mean(kpi, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Can someone please show me how to customize this animation so that it looks like the second picture I uploaded?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that your question considers frames as states (`transition_states()`), while the code you provide considers it as times (`transition_time()`). When running your code, the animation considers `frame_number` as a numeric variable so there is not really such thing as frame #1 on which you could calculate summaries. Could you clarify this point?

Comment: @ Dan: thank you for your reply! Let me think how to answer...